# Tratar retorno da função getdetails() da api do maps no angular/ionic

Tags: angular, ionic, typescript, google-maps-api-3

Busco os lugares próximos com `nearbySearch()`, que retorna um array de objetos, desse retorno uso o `place_id` para buscar os detalhes `getDetails()`, que retorna um objeto `"place"`. Dentro de um loop quando vou atribuir o valor de place para `this.detalhes[i]` da esse erro.

> TypeError: _this.detalhes is undefined

Segue o código

```
declare var google;

@Injectable()

export class JsMapsProvider {

  map: any;

  places : Array<any>;

  detalhes: Array<any>;

  constructor(public geolocation : Geolocation) { }

  init(location, element){

    let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude);

    let opts = {
      center: latLng,
      zoom: 15,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    this.map = new google.maps.Map(element.nativeElement, opts);

    this.getFarmas(latLng).then( (results : Array<any>)=>{
      this.places = results;
      console.log(this.places);      

      for(let i = 0 ;i < results.length ; i++)
      {
        //loop para pegar valor bool e verificar se está aberta ou não e usar no marcador
        for(let i = 0 ;i < results.length ; i++){
          if(results[i].opening_hours == null){
            results[i].aberto = 'Não há informações sobre o horário de funcionamento';
          }else if(!results[i].opening_hours.open_now){
            results[i].aberto = 'Fechado neste momento';
          }else{
            results[i].aberto = 'Aberto neste momento';
          }
        }

        var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(this.map);
        var request = {
          placeId: results[i].place_id,
          //fields: ['formatted_phone_number']
        };

        service.getDetails(request,(place , status)=>{
              if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
              if(place.formatted_phone_number == null){
                  place.formatted_phone_number = 'Telefone não cadastrado';
                }
                this.detalhes[i] = place;


              }
            } 
          );

        this.createMarker(results[i]);

        console.log(this.detalhes);
      }
    },(status)=>console.log(status));

    this.addMarker(this.map);

  }

  getFarmas(latLng){
    var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(this.map);

    let request = {
        location : latLng,
        //radius : 2000 ,
        types: ['pharmacy'],
        rankBy: google.maps.places.RankBy.DISTANCE
    };
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        service.nearbySearch(request,function(results,status){
              if(status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK)
              {                 
                  resolve(results);
                  console.log(results);
              }else
              {
                  reject(status);
              }

        });

    });
  }
```

Comment: Não seria `this.detalhes.push(places)` ou `this.detalhes = places`?

Comment: Olá Marconi, ja tinha tentado com o push mas o resultado não era o que eu queria, resolvi com a ajuda da resposta do Vinicius Lourenço. Mas muito obrigado pela ajuda!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A variável `this.detalhes` nem foi inicializada e por isso dá erro ao tentar atribuir algum valor. Inicialize a variável assim:

```
detalhes: Array<any> = [];
```

Ou

```
detalhes: any[] = [];
```

Além disso, você está atribuindo `this.detalhes[i] = place;` como se ouvesse algum valor já pré-definido no índice `i`. Se houver, inicialize em algum ponto a variável `this.detalhes` com alguns valores, caso contrário, siga a sugestão do @Marconi e use `this.detalhes.push(places)` para adicionar itens a sua lista `detalhes`.

Comment: Muito obrigado Vinicius, resolveu meu problema!!!!!!